# Ilogger logs are not being sent to application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6 and I have application insights configured.
In my startup I have

```
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher();
```

And in my appsettings I have an instrumentation key configured:

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "key"
  }
```

I also configured the log levels

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to use Ilogger to send custom messages, they are not being sent to application insights.

```
    logger.LogWarning("Object with id {id} not found.", id);
```

In my console I see all sorts of AppRequests but none of these contain the error message I put in my Ilogger. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating my package(s) to

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.20.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Kubernetes" Version="2.0.1" />
```

Comment: I have Nlog.Ilogger how do I ensure my app insights is getting the logs?